# Run each() but only apply on the first result

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I turn the first p to red?

I'm using `each()` because I need to search for all the P's. But I only want the code to work on the first result only, "exit" after that or something like that.

How can I do that with jQuery?

PS: This is a simple example, the code is more complex than that, so please don't suggest something like `$('p').eq(0)` or a CSS way... I need to do this with jQuery running the each method.

Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/ybr2qh46/

```
<p>name 1</p>
<p>name 2</p>
<p>name 3</p>

(function($){
    $('p').each( function(){
    $(this).css( 'color', 'red');
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('p')` will do the job much better than jQuery's `each()`...for anyone who doesn't _need_ jQuery.

Comment: *"This is a simple example, the code is more complex than that"* then this nippet doesn't represent your code/problem. How about you including some snippet that properly describes/shows the problem, and why you need to `each` over the entire list although you want to execute the code only for the first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `return false` in order to stop the loop from continuing to the next element:

```js
(function($){
    $('p').each( function(){
    $(this).css( 'color', 'red');
    return false;
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>name 1</p>
<p>name 2</p>
<p>name 3</p>
```

Another option - if you want the loop to continue (but still want to change only the first element) - you can check if that element is the first one:

```js
(function($){
    $('p').each( function(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      $(this).css( 'color', 'red');
    }
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>name 1</p>
<p>name 2</p>
<p>name 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `.first()` method. It's used to select first selector if there is 1 or more than 1 selectors.

```js
$('p').first().css( 'color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>name 1</p>
<p>name 2</p>
<p>name 3</p>
```

---

Another option (*must use each method*):

```js
var item = Array.from($('p').each(function (){}))[0];

$(item).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>name 1</p>
<p>name 2</p>
<p>name 3</p>
```

Comment: OP: *I need to do this with jQuery running the each method*

Comment: This is no different than `$('p').eq(0).css(...` which OP said they don't want

Comment: @Mohammad *You can try to use...* NOT **You could...**

Comment: @charlietfl *please don't suggest something like $('p').eq(0)*. I don't suggest to use `$('p').eq(0)`

Comment: But that is  what `first()` does .... it does exact same thing as `eq(0)`

Comment: @charlietfl So, we need to pull a request to jquery team that they should remove `eq(0)` method because they already have `first`? Or removing `first` because of `eq(0)`?

Comment: No that is not the point at all. Whether jQuery includes convenience methods that do same as others is completely irrelevant. OP however clearly stated they don't want that approach....read the question again